# Add a group in assignee field using work flow - sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i want to set a group in assignee field in sharepoint using workflow.

I just know the group name from Active Directory

```
SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();
workflowProperties.Item["Assignee"]= @"servername\groupname";
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

after tht code add the following code too

```
workflowProperties.Item.Update();
```

Comment: I used it, but in list i get the error, what i think
since the type of the field is 'Person or Group', we have to provide some id against it group,

Comment: I got the solution

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(this.SiteURL))
            {
                SPGroupCollection group = site.RootWeb.Groups;
                string groupname = string.Empty;
                foreach (SPGroup item in group)
                {
                    if (item.Name.ToLower().Equals("Your group name"))
                    {
                        workflowProperties.Item["Approver"] = item.ID;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                workflowProperties.Item.Update();
            }